# select a word in a text blob in ruby based on a pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I have a text blob and I would like to select URL's based on whether they have .png or .jpg. I would like to select the entire word based on a pattern.

For example in this blob:

```
width='17'></a>&nbsp;<a href='http://click.e.groupon.com/?  qs=94bee0ddf93da5b3903921bfbe17116f859915d3a978c042430abbcd51be55d8df40eceba3b1c44e'     style=\"text-decoration: none;\">\n<img alt='Facebook' border='0' height='18'   src='http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/gw-email/facebook.jpg' style='display: i
```

I'd like to select the image:

http://s3.grouponcdn.com/email/images/gw-email/facebook.jpg

Can I use nokogiri on an html text blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use nokogiri, and you should!

Here's a simple snippet:

```
require "nokogiri"
str = "....your blob"
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
html_doc.css("a").collect{|e| e.attributes["href"].value}.select{|e| e.index(".png") || e.index(".jpeg") }
```

Comment: i changed the "a" to "img" and the "href" to "src" but this worked beautifully, thanks!

Comment: You might want to use `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment()` for simpler and more exact representation of your contents.

Answer (score 4):

Using Nokogiri and XPath:

```
frag = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str) # Don't construct an entire HTML document
images = frag.xpath('.//img/@src').map(&:text).grep /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)\z/
```

The XPath says:

- `.//` — anywhere in this fragment
- `img` — find all the `<img>` elements

  - `/@src` — now find the `src` attribute of each

Then we:

- `map(&:text)` – convert all the `Nokogiri::XML::Attr` to the value of the attribute.
- `grep` - find only those strings in the array that end with the appropriate text.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to find urls ending in .jpg or .png a pattern like this should do it.

```
https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:jpg|png)
```

Comment: This will fail if you have e.g. `<a href="http://foo.html">foo</a> <img src="http://blah.com/img.png">` as it will capture from the first http up until the png.